# Symfony3 custom form with 2 select on same entity

Tags: symfony

I have an interessant problem. I work with Symfony3.2 with last version.

I have one entity called 'Meeting' with 3 fields :

- date: datetime
- hour: time
- category: MeetingCategory

I can have severals meeting per day per category.

First Step :
I need to pass the category to my form for only display meeting of one category.

Second Step :
When i display my form, i need to present 2 inputs :

1. select date available for meeting
2. select hour available for day select just before.

For my 1st problem, i have read many articles in this subject, but when i try, its a fail.
I have tried to make request on controller and pass choice list in form.
I have tried to pass category on form, and use query-builder option in entity field...
I haven't more idea for complete this.

For my 2nd problem, i continue to search a good idea ^^ I read some tips on official documentation :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data

Its for this reason, I need to manage the form in form type. Not in controller.

Thx for your help and your tips ;)

---

Yep sorry i didn't post my code because i have made a lot of test. I post my last example :

controller:

```
$defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
    ->add('date', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'MeetingBundle:Meeting', 'choice_label' => 'date',
        'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'label' => 'label.meeting',
        'query_builder' => function (MeetingRepository $cr) use ($category) {
            return $cr->getMeetingByCategory($category);
        }
    ))
    ->add('hour', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'MeetingBundle:Meeting', 'choice_label' => 'hour',
        'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'label' => 'label.hour',
        'query_builder' => function (MeetingRepository $cr) use ($category) {
            return $cr->getMeetingByCategory($category);
        }
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

Repository :

```
public function getMeetingByCategory(Category $category)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('meeting');

    $now = new \DateTime('now');

    $qb->where($qb->expr()->gte('meeting.date', ':date'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('meeting.category', ':category'))
        ->setParameters(array(
            'date' => $now->format('Y-m-d'),
            'category' => $category,
        ));

    return $qb;
}
```

When i try to put the form in SpecialMeetingType file, i have a lot of problem to pass argument in form, then in closure.

Comment: Please post the code of your form types and corresponding controller actions...

Comment: You have 2 complex problems and you're tackling both at the same time. Try to get Step 1 working, if you have problems then post your code along with the errors/problems with that specific code. As it stands your question is wide open and too difficult to help you get started on an answer.

Comment: Thx @ehymel. I agree, but i search wich solution i can use for these 2 steps. When the first step is solved, if solution for step 2 is incompatible, its a fail ^^. I focus first step now and i come back with code.